# Ansible SSL certificate verify failed

Tags: ansible

I am trying to setup Ansible to manage Windows hosts.  The hosts will be using SSL certificates issued from an internal CA.  I have configured the Windows host per the instructions [here](https://www.ansible.com/blog/connecting-to-a-windows-host).  But when I try connecting using the module win_ping, I get:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='winhost@mydomain.local', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)'),))"
```

I've confirmed that when connecting to the Windows host on port 5986, the certificate issued by my CA is the one being used.  And I tried specifying the CA certificate using ansible_winrm_ca_trust_path as a variable in my hosts file but it's not validating the certificate.  Here is what I have in the hosts file:

```
local:
  control:

win_test:
  hosts:
    winhost.mydomain.local:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_user: ansible@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
    ansible_password: "#######"
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
    ansible_winrm_ca_trust_path: /home/my_username@mydomain.local/ansible/CA.cert
```

So, what am I doing wrong with certificate validation?  As an FYI, I'm running Ansible v2.9.2 with Python 2.7.5.

**Update**:  I switched to Python3 and am getting the same error.  Here is the verbose output of the error:

```
ansible 2.9.2
  config file = /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/myself@mydomain.local/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/hosts, line 12, column 5, found a duplicate dict key (ansible_connection). Using last defined
value only.

Skipping empty key (control) in group (local)
Parsed /home/myself@mydomain.local/ansible/hosts inventory source with yaml plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
Using module file /home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_ping.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<winhost.mydomain.local> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL on PORT 5986 TO winhost.mydomain.local
creating Kerberos CC at /tmp/tmpwetofduv
calling kinit with subprocess for principal ansible@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
kinit succeeded for principal ansible@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
<winhost.mydomain.local> WINRM CONNECT: transport=kerberos endpoint=https://winhost.mydomain.local:5986/wsman
<winhost.mydomain.local> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='winhost.mydomain.local', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/home/myself@mydomain.local/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 773, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1033, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 645, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)
```

Comment: On the Windows box install WireShark. Make a capture of the connection from the ansible host to WinRM service. In the capture search for SSL/TLS Alert packet. Go up in the capture and find the certificate. Try to validate it with the CA certificates that are installed on the Linux machine. Post your progress so I can help you on the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back when running Python 2.7. Switching Ansible to use Python 3 solved the problem. Since Python 2 is EOL and out of support you really should do that anyway.

Install Python 3 (if it isn't already installed) and add something like `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` to your ansible configuration file.